# Mono FileSystemWatcher for Mac Opens all the files it watches

Tags: c#, macos, mono

I am using Mono 4.6.2

When I create FileSystemWatcher to monitor a directory on Mac, it appears the watcher is opening all the files in that directory.  I can see this in two ways:

1. when I open a large directory, it throws "too many open files" exception.
2. I can see all the files are listed under "Activity Monitor->Information->Open Files and Ports" for my program.

This is how I created my watcher:

```
var watcher = new FileSystemWatcher {
    Path = path.LocalPath,
    IncludeSubdirectories = true
};
watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.CreationTime | NotifyFilters.FileName | 
                       NotifyFilters.DirectoryName | NotifyFilters.LastWrite;
watcher.Changed += FileSystemWatcher_Changed;
watcher.Renamed += FileSystemWatcher_Renamed;
```

Is it designed this way? Is there a workaround for this issue?

Comment: Seems to be a known issue: [see this about DNX](https://github.com/aspnet/DotNetTools/issues/13). I don't see any kind of work-around though other than `export MONO_MANAGED_WATCHER disabled`, which basically turns off the ability to watch files. Some have luck with it `export MONO_MANAGED_WATCHER enabled`, but report having high CPU usage and slow response times. If you look at [the FileSystemWatcher source code](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/System/System.IO/FileSystemWatcher.cs) you can see how it uses `MONO_MANAGED_WATCHER`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this ticket [#bugzilla.xamarin](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=43462#c9).

Workaround: run the `GC` for every iteration.

```
//Execute:
mcs test.cs
ulimit -n 96
mono test.exe
```